# Wrong Base URLs only on Order Success Page with Multi Stores in Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2

I have created multi stores website with multi locales. Everything is working fine except the base URL on the order success page is wrong and showing the URLs of the default store in the navigation links, logo, and custom links using the function getBaseUrl or getUrl.

Even though we are getting console errors like 
`Access to font at 'http://blizz-relaunch.local/pub/static/version1572514278/frontend/Venedor/galabau/de_DE/fonts/Blank-Theme-Icons/Blank-Theme-Icons.woff' from origin 'http://galabau-relaunch.local' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Please help me to rectify this error.[image]

[image]